# Redirect from spring controller with post parameter

Tags: spring, redirect

I want to redirect to another page(outside my application) from spring controller with post parameter. I search a lot but didn't any solution.

Answer (score 5):

You will not be able to add a POST, but you can redirect with GET.  Do the following:

```
@RequestMapping("/redirectMe")
public void redirectMe (HttpServletResponse response){
    response.sendRedirect("http://redirected.com/form?someGetParam=foo");
}
```

Comment: Why post is not possible? I have problem with get when I have collection as parameter generated URL is then: `http://localhost:8080/myApp/A/result.form?parameters=SomeName&parameters=SoemField` which leads to `parameters=SomeName`. Any idea?

Comment: When you advise the browser to redirect, as is stated in this question, there is nowhere to define which http verb is being used.  It will always be a GET.  If you need to POST, you will need to deploy a javascript client to do so, and you will need to make sure you are not doing cross site scripting.

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this

```
@RequestMapping(value="/someUrl",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String myFunc(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response,Map model){
    //do sume stuffs
     return "redirect:/anotherUrl"; //gets redirected to the url '/anotherUrl'
}

@RequestMapping(value="/anotherUrl",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String myAnotherFunc(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response){
    //do sume stuffs
     return "someView"; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

easy way for to do:

```
    @PostMapping("/redirectPostToPost")
public ModelAndView redirectPostToPost(HttpServletRequest request) {
    request.setAttribute(
      View.RESPONSE_STATUS_ATTRIBUTE, HttpStatus.TEMPORARY_REDIRECT);
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/redirectedPostToPost");
}
@PostMapping("/redirectedPostToPost")
public ModelAndView redirectedPostToPost() {
    return new ModelAndView("redirection");
}
```